# Is there any tool can output the paths of the root to each node of a JSON?

Tags: json

Say I have a JSON:

```
{
  "aaa": 111,
  "bbb":222,
  "ccc": {
    "mmm": 333,
    "nnn": 444
  }
}
```

Is there any tool can output all paths from the root to each nodes? So I can get a list of paths:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc/mmm
ccc/nnn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tool that just outputs paths probably doesn't exist.  Such a tool would have very little use in the real world.

There are however tools that could generate such results.  [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for instance could do this relatively easily with the following filter:

```
def dump_paths(name): name as $name |
    (objects | to_entries[] | "\($name)/\(.key)" as $key | .value | dump_paths($key)) //
    (arrays | to_entries[] | "\($name)[\(.key)]" as $key | .value | dump_paths($key)) //
    $name
    ;
dump_paths("")
```

It would produce the following strings:

```
/aaa
/bbb
/ccc/mmm
/ccc/nnn
```